# "is there" or "if there is" which one is more easy to understand and hear?

Tags: word-usage

this professor is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=108) (expression_1)

> is there a cat on this image, output one, or is there no cat on this image, output zero

change this expression as (expression_2)

> if there is a cat on this image, output one; or if there is no cat on this image, output zero.

in the context of class lecture, which one is more easy to understand and hear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person talking in the video seems to be a non-native English speaker whose English is good but far from perfect.  Since English has become a common language, it's normal to hear non-native speakers say things that are not grammatical or not idiomatic, and so you have to figure out what the speaker *means* to say.

In English, when you place the verb before the subject it normally forms a question.  In this context, you have to decide if the professor is making a *statement* or if he is asking a *rhetorical question* -- that is, a question he intends to answer himself.  Either is fine, as these are two different ways to express the same thing:

Keep in mind that this topic is computational algorithms, which you can think of as a series of yes/no questions.  It's then reasonable to express this as a kind of *query*:

> Is there a cat in the picture? (if yes) Then output one.  Is there no cat in the picture?  Then output zero.

This is perfectly natural, as the language imitates the way the algorithm works. Otherwise you can write it as a statement, as in your second sentence:

> If there is a cat in the image, then output one; otherwise output zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And which one is easier to understand for a native English person? Considering they are in a classroom and there is no punctuation to help to get lecturer's point.

Comment: @baojieqh  both are easy to understand.  Which you use depends on your speaking style, and which you think will make more sense to your audience.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Expression 2 makes more sense grammatically.

In Expression 1, you're asking a question instead of stating the two outcomes, therefore I would punctuate as follows:

> Is there a cat on this image? Output one.
>   Is there no cat on this image? Output zero.

Comment: agree the answer to option 1 is yes or no. is there a cat in the image? yes: output 1, no: output 0